# Code not executing and displaying in Html (Flask)

Tags: html, flask

#Flask Code

```
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

posts = [
    {
        'author': 'User',
        'title': 'Test',
        'content': 'First post',
        'date_posted': '2021, 4 ,13',
    },

    {
        'author': 'User2',
        'title': 'Flask is cool',
        'content': 'Flask testing',
        'date_posted': '2021, 4 ,14'
    }
]

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/home')
def hello():
    return render_template('home.html', posts=posts)

#ignore this
@app.route('/about')
def about():
    return render_template('about.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

#HTML Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

    {% for post in posts %}
        <p>By {{ posts.author }} on {{ posts.date_posted }}</p>
        <p>By {{ post.content }}</p>
    {% endfor %}

</body>
</html>
```

the for loop is executing but the values in the dict. are not displaying, I am very new in flask
so I'm pretty sure I have to add in some extra code..? Any help is appreciated :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your loop variable `post` inside your `for` loop instead of `posts`.

```html
{% for post in posts %}
<p>By {{ post.author }} on {{ post.date_posted }}</p>
<p>By {{ post.content }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```